# Agregar valores de una lista a un diccionario python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy haciendo un código el cual tengo una lista de lista la cual contiene un nombre y un entero (el cual es su edad) y quiero que apartir de su edad se vayan a agregando a una 'categoría' si le pudieramos llamar de esa manera, este es mi código:

```
listP = [['john', 20], ['alberto', 20], ['natalia', 30]]
newDict = {}

for i in range(len(listP)):
    temp = listP[i][1]
    if temp >= 18 and temp <= 24:
        newDict['18-24'] = listP[i][0]
    elif temp >= 25 and temp <= 35:
        newDict['25-35'] = listP[i][0]
```

Como salida obtengo:

```
{'18-24': 'alberto', '25-35': 'natalia'}
```

Y debería obtener de salida:

```
{'18-24': 'alberto, jonh', '25-35': 'natalia'}
```

De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que cada vez que un condicional se cumple y haces `newDict[clave] = listP[i][0]` asignas una nueva cadena como valor de la clave.

Tendrías que concatenar el nombre nuevo a la cadena que ya hay como clave asociada al rango, si la clave ya existe en el diccionario, o crear una nueva pareja clave-valor si no existe previamente, algo así:

```
listP = [['john', 20], ['alberto', 20], ['natalia', 30]]

new_dict = {}

for nombre, edad in listP:
    if  18 <= edad <= 24:
        if '18-24' in new_dict:
            new_dict['18-24'] += (', ' + nombre)
        else:
            new_dict['18-24'] = nombre

    elif 25 <= edad <= 35:
        if '25-35' in new_dict:
            new_dict['25-35'] += (', ' + nombre)
        else:
            new_dict['25-35'] = nombre
```

Concatenar cadenas es una tarea muy ineficiente dado que son inmutables y cada vez que concatenas creas un nuevo objeto. En su lugar podrías usar una lista y luego aplicar `str.join` para crear las cadenas si lo deseas:

```
listP = [['john', 20], ['alberto', 20], ['natalia', 30]]

new_dict = {}

for nombre, edad in listP:
    if  18 <= edad <= 24:
        if '18-24' in new_dict:
            new_dict['18-24'].append(nombre)
        else:
            new_dict['18-24'] = [nombre]

    elif 25 <= edad <= 35:
        if '25-35' in new_dict:
            new_dict['25-35'].append(nombre)
        else:
            new_dict['25-35'] = [nombre]
```

O puedes usar `collections.defaultdict` que te evita la comprobación explicita de la existencia de la clave:

```
from collections import defaultdict

listP = [['john', 20], ['alberto', 20], ['natalia', 30]]

new_dict = defaultdict(list)

for nombre, edad in listP:
    if  18 <= edad <= 24:
        new_dict['18-24'].append(nombre)
    elif 25 <= edad <= 35:
        new_dict['25-35'].append(nombre)
```

Posteriormente puedes recorrer el diccionario y crear las cadenas si no quieres listas como valores:

```
for key in new_dict:
    new_dict[key] = ", ".join(new_dict[key])
```

Con lo que obtienes:

```
>>> new_dict
{'18-24': 'john, alberto', '25-35': 'natalia'}
```

---

`for indice in range(len(lista))` es un forma muy ineficiente y poco "pytónica" de recorrer una lista. A no ser que pretendas alterar el contenido del iterable mientras iteras, es siempre mejor opción usar `for-in` para tales menesteres.

Comment: Muchas gracias @FJSevilla la segunda opción me funcionó muy bien.